# What character/species is this?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Who is the "question mark" character in the elevator?

[image: Screen capture of strange character]

It looks a little like a Bith but it's not quite the same (as you can see from the Bith in the Cantina and the picture below).  I can't seem to find this guy in the Bitizen Album.

[image: Screen capture of regular Bith]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Bith.  The characters in the album often look different from the elevator renders.  But, if you look in the store, you can see it is clearly a Bith.

The album can be tricky, too.  Every time you enter, the characters change outfits and skins to one of the different variations.

[image: Bith Store]

[image: Bith Album 1]

[image: Bith Album 2]

Comment: I hadn't noticed that since I'd never opened the Bitizen store before.  I guess you're right but it's still confusing because there's another Bith bitizen that DOES match the album picture.  I don't think I can add a picture to a comment so I added it to my original question.

Comment: Yeah!  It's very confusing, but if you go into the album a bunch of time you'll see them dressed in different outfits, and with different skins.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it isn't just the clothes and skins that are different.  The shape and size of the head and eyes are different.  That's what threw me off originally.

Comment: I don't judge … I just explain. ;-)