# How do I figure out which ? Bitizen I am seeing?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'll admit it, I'm not really much of a Star Wars fanatic, and as such, I have trouble  naming even the supposedly "simplest" bitizens in Tiny Death Star.

As such, when a ? bitizen appears, I have immense trouble figuring out the name of the bitizen so I can at least see if I have any floors I can get unique scenes with.

Is there a guide that lists the picture of the bitizen along with the name of it?  The only "real" characters I know are Boba Fett, the guy with the green suit.

Right now I'm kinda stuck; I have a character with a brown hood and yellow glowing eyes, and I have no clue what his/her/it name is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What character/species is this?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147151/what-character-species-is-this)

Comment: Sounds like a Jawa.

Comment: In the future, if you are having trouble with an in-game identification of something, please snap a screenshot and post it with the question.  It will help significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a guide to this located within the game itself!  Click on the menu tab located in the lower right hand corner.  Next click on Album and click on the Bitizens tab.

This is an album of all the different species and characters.  Tap on the picture and it will give you a small bio of the bitizen or species.

One thing to note, the pictures will frequently change colors if you go into and come back into this album.  This is to show you all of the different permutations of coloring of the species.

I've attached a picture which I believe shows the character you are asking about (the Jawa).

[image: Album]                        [image: jawa]

Comment: The problem is, what if the ? bitizen I have is also a ? in the album?

Comment: Whenever a bitizen appears in the elevator, they will appear in the album.  In order to appear, the species or character must unlock first.

Answer (score 3):

That is a Jawa.

Go to your album. You can find lots of interesting information there concerning the characters and species that inhibit Tiny Death Star as bitizens, including their names.

Also, when special characters pop up for the 1st time, the game would always prompt you to look for them on the various floors in TDS, mentioning their name.